# How to hook chrome extension to network browser traffic

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to write a chrome extension which intercepts network traffic and modify the data.

I would appreciate if someone can tell me exactly which API I should use for this and where I can find the documentation.

Comment: chrome.webRequest can be used to monitor the traffic but it can't modify the response *body* in Chrome. For that you'll need to use chrome.debugger API - search for "intercept" in [Network docs for devtools protocol](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network#method-setRequestInterception).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make use of the [webRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest) API and have a look at their [events](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#events).

Create a manifest with permissions `activeTab` to get permissions for the current tab on which you are on, and the [url pattern](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/match_patterns) you wish the extension to be enabled for. The `webRequestBlocking` permission needs to be set specifically for blocking and modifying traffic.

### manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "network intercepter",
  "description": "intercept/modify/block data",
  "version": "1.0",

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },

  "host_permissions": [
    "https://*.google.com/*"
  ],

  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking"
  ]
}
```

Create a background script and start adding webRequest listener based on which actions you want to perform. [This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/BlockingResponse) was useful for me when making those choices.

### background.js

```
var onBeforeSendHeadersListener = function(details) {
    // view request + headers to be send
    console.log(details);

    // block XMLHttpRequests by returning object with key "cancel"
    if (details.type == "xmlhttprequest") {
        return {
            cancel: true
        };
    }

    // modify the user agent of all script resources by changing the requestHeaders and then return an object with key "requestHeaders"
    if (details.type == "script") {
        for (var i = 0; i < details.requestHeaders.length; i++) {
            if (details.requestHeaders[i].name == "User-Agent") {
                details.requestHeaders[i].value = "I'm not a bot";
            }
        }
        return {
            "requestHeaders": details.requestHeaders
        };
    }
}


var onBeforeRequestListener = function(details) {
    // all images will now be loaded from this location instead
    // CAREFUL! CROSS ORIGIN REQUESTS WILL NOT BE BLOCKED WITH CHROME EXTENSIONS
    if (details.type == "image") {
        return {
            "redirectUrl": "https://foo.bar/image.jpg"
        };
    }
}


chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(onBeforeSendHeadersListener, {
    urls: ["https://*.google.com/*"]
}, ["requestHeaders", "blocking"]);

chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(onBeforeRequestListener, {
    urls: ["https://*.google.com/*"]
}, ["requestBody", "blocking"]);
```

Visit chrome://extensions and open the background page, and go to its console. Then visit https://google.com normally, you will see that all images are changed to their new location, the XHR's are blocked, and the script resources have their User Agent changed, and in the background console you will find the requests that were made.

Comment: See the new version of the manifest.json
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66867507/4349191
The url should be places into the separate `"host_permissions"` prop

Comment: Thank you I updated the manifest.json

Comment: what about responseBody?